# what is the correct datetime format for mySQL in 24 hour time?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

When I tried to insert a datetime into my MAC's local mysql table from `$sudo mysql`>>`$use DB` in terminal, I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '('2015-10-07 13:21:30',5)),
>   convert(datetime('2015-10-07 13:41:30',5)))' at line 1

This is the insert:

```
INSERT INTO log VALUES (1,28, convert(datetime('2015-10-07 13:21:30',5)), convert(datetime('2015-10-07 13:41:30',5)));
```

Comment: no difference after i correct them. ive tried several differnt date formats

Answer (score 1):

According to mysql's dev page (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), the default format of datetime in mySQL is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'. In your case, if you have a DATETIME or DATE column you don't need to call any conversion function to insert to it a datetime, just insert your date as is: '2015-10-07 13:21:30' and you should be ok.

In general, try to avoid conversions when inserting data as that affects the database performance especially if you are using it actively.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

when i created the table i set a column to an `int` instead of `datetime` so of course it didnt accept `datetime`. when i changed it back it worked... orz